# How to retrieve the routing tables in JSON format (linux)?

Tags: linux, ip, route, iproute2, json

The `ip` command is able to return some of its results in JSON format, but it seems to be unable to format the routing table(s).

Here are some examples of what I mean.

List of all addresses: `ip --json address show`

```
[{ ... },{
    "ifindex": 2,
    "ifname": "eth0",
    "flags": ["BROADCAST","MULTICAST","UP","LOWER_UP"],
    "mtu": 1500,
    "qdisc": "fq_codel",
    "master": "lan0",
    "operstate": "UP",
    "group": "default",
    "txqlen": 1000,
    "link_type": "ether",
    "address": "44:89:3f:e9:a8:08",
    "broadcast": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
    "addr_info": []
},{ ... }]
```

Interface list: `ip --json link show`

```
[{ ... },{
    "ifindex": 2,
    "ifname": "eth0",
    "flags": ["BROADCAST","MULTICAST","UP","LOWER_UP"],
    "mtu": 1500,
    "qdisc": "fq_codel",
    "master": "lan0",
    "operstate": "UP",
    "linkmode": "DEFAULT",
    "group": "default",
    "txqlen": 1000,
    "link_type": "ether",
    "address": "44:89:3f:e9:a8:08",
    "broadcast": "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"
},{ ... }]
```

I was expecting to retrieve the route list in JSON as well, but I could only retrieve its plaintext version:
Route list: `ip --json route list` (it's still in plaintext)

```
1.1.1.2 via 192.168.255.11 dev lan0 table hopper src 192.168.254.1 metric 10
default via 10.19.1.4 dev wg0 metric 5
default via 192.168.255.11 dev lan0 metric 6
10.19.1.0/24 dev wg0 scope link
124.214.110.113 via 192.168.255.11 dev lan0 metric 4
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-fea43fdf31f1 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-6f9e681d15b0 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown
192.168.0.0/16 dev lan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.254.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev wan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.9
192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.255.11 dev lan0 metric 3
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1
multicast 239.255.255.250/32 from 192.168.1.109/32 table default proto 17 unresolved
```

Since I couldn't find a solution anywhere, I'll answer my own question and leave here what I did.
Who knows, maybe someday I'll need it again, or maybe someone else will be having the same problem! :-)

Comment: Your command works on Debian Buster "ip --json route list" : [{"dst":"default","gateway":"192.168.10.254","dev":"eno1","protocol":"dhcp","metric":100,"flags":[]},{"dst":"172.17.0.0/16","dev":"docker0","protocol":"kernel","scope":"link","prefsrc":"172.17.0.1","flags":[]},{"dst":"192.168.10.0/24","dev":"eno1","protocol":"kernel","scope":"link","prefsrc":"192.168.10.154","metric":100,"flags":[]}]

Comment: Oh, that's very cool! I was using ubuntu 18.04 LTS when I got into this issue. However, after reading your comment I tried with the 19.04 and it did work there too indeed.
So, this bug could probably be limited to ubuntu versions < 19.04.
That's very nice to know... and thank you very much for the tip! ^_^

Answer (score 3):

So, here's what I did.
I used the command `jq` to parse the result of `ip route list table all` using a regex, transforming the output to JSON.
Feel free to play around with `jq`, and [click here to use an online sandbox](https://jqterm.com/b0226a09293cc5856a262db7ca3c644c?query=split%28%22%5Cn%22%29%20%7Cmap%28select%28length%20%3E%200%29%29%20%7C%20map%28capture%28%22%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Cbroadcast%3Ebroadcast%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Clocal%3Elocal%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Cmulticast%3Emulticast%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3A%20%3F%28%3F%3Cnetwork%3E.*%3F%29%20%29%28%3F%3Afrom%20%28%3F%3Cfrom%3E%5C%5CS%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Avia%20%28%3F%3Cvia%3E%5C%5CS%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Adev%20%28%3F%3Cdev%3E%5C%5CS%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Atable%20%28%3F%3Ctable%3E%5C%5CS%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Aproto%20%28%3F%3Cproto%3E%5C%5CS%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Ascope%20%28%3F%3Cscope%3E%5C%5CS%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Asrc%20%28%3F%3Csrc%3E%5C%5CS%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Ametric%20%28%3F%3Cmetric%3E%5C%5Cd%2B%29%20%3F%29%3F%28%3F%3Clinkdown%3Elinkdown%29%3F%28%3F%3Cunresolved%3Eunresolved%29%3F%22%3B%20%22g%22%29%29&slurp=true&raw-input=true) already loaded with this solution. 
This is the complete command:

`ip route list table all | jq --raw-input --slurp 'split("\n") | map(capture("^(?:(?<broadcast>broadcast) ?)?(?:(?<local>local) ?)?(?:(?<multicast>multicast) ?)?(?: ?(?<network>.*?) )(?:from (?<from>\\S+) ?)?(?:via (?<via>\\S+) ?)?(?:dev (?<dev>\\S+) ?)?(?:table (?<table>\\S+) ?)?(?:proto (?<proto>\\S+) ?)?(?:scope (?<scope>\\S+) ?)?(?:src (?<src>\\S+) ?)?(?:metric (?<metric>\\d+) ?)?(?<linkdown>linkdown)?(?<unresolved>unresolved)?"; "g"))'`

And this is the output:

```
[
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "1.1.1.2",
    "from": null,
    "via": "192.168.255.11",
    "dev": "lan0",
    "table": "hopper",
    "proto": null,
    "scope": null,
    "src": "192.168.254.1",
    "metric": "10",
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "default",
    "from": null,
    "via": "10.19.1.4",
    "dev": "wg0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": null,
    "scope": null,
    "src": null,
    "metric": "5",
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "default",
    "from": null,
    "via": "192.168.255.11",
    "dev": "lan0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": null,
    "scope": null,
    "src": null,
    "metric": "6",
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "10.19.1.0/24",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "wg0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": null,
    "scope": "link",
    "src": null,
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "124.214.110.113",
    "from": null,
    "via": "192.168.255.11",
    "dev": "lan0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": null,
    "scope": null,
    "src": null,
    "metric": "4",
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "172.17.0.0/16",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "docker0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": "kernel",
    "scope": "link",
    "src": "172.17.0.1",
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": "linkdown",
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "172.18.0.0/16",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "br-fea43fdf31f1",
    "table": null,
    "proto": "kernel",
    "scope": "link",
    "src": "172.18.0.1",
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "172.19.0.0/16",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "br-6f9e681d15b0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": "kernel",
    "scope": "link",
    "src": "172.19.0.1",
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": "linkdown",
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "192.168.0.0/16",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "lan0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": "kernel",
    "scope": "link",
    "src": "192.168.254.1",
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "192.168.1.0/24",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "wan0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": "kernel",
    "scope": "link",
    "src": "192.168.1.9",
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "192.168.1.0/24",
    "from": null,
    "via": "192.168.255.11",
    "dev": "lan0",
    "table": null,
    "proto": null,
    "scope": null,
    "src": null,
    "metric": "3",
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": "broadcast",
    "local": null,
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "127.0.0.0",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "lo",
    "table": "local",
    "proto": "kernel",
    "scope": "link",
    "src": "127.0.0.1",
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": "local",
    "multicast": null,
    "network": "127.0.0.1",
    "from": null,
    "via": null,
    "dev": "lo",
    "table": "local",
    "proto": "kernel",
    "scope": "host",
    "src": "127.0.0.1",
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": null
  },
  {
    "broadcast": null,
    "local": null,
    "multicast": "multicast",
    "network": "239.255.255.250/32",
    "from": "192.168.1.109/32",
    "via": null,
    "dev": null,
    "table": "default",
    "proto": "17",
    "scope": null,
    "src": null,
    "metric": null,
    "linkdown": null,
    "unresolved": "unresolved"
  }
]
```

That's already enough for what I needed but, if you have some time to spare, there's still room for improvement: all the null values could be removed, the "metric" values could be transformed to numbers, and "broadcast", "local", "multicast", "linkdown" and "unresolved" could be booleans.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a cli tool called `jc` that will convert `netstat -r` and `route` command output to JSON.

```
$ jc netstat -rn | jq
[
  {
    "destination": "0.0.0.0",
    "gateway": "192.168.71.2",
    "genmask": "0.0.0.0",
    "route_flags": "UG",
    "mss": 0,
    "window": 0,
    "irtt": 0,
    "iface": "ens33",
    "kind": "route",
    "route_flags_pretty": [
      "UP",
      "GATEWAY"
    ]
  },
  {
    "destination": "172.17.0.0",
    "gateway": "0.0.0.0",
    "genmask": "255.255.0.0",
    "route_flags": "U",
    "mss": 0,
    "window": 0,
    "irtt": 0,
    "iface": "docker0",
    "kind": "route",
    "route_flags_pretty": [
      "UP"
    ]
  },
  {
    "destination": "192.168.71.0",
    "gateway": "0.0.0.0",
    "genmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "route_flags": "U",
    "mss": 0,
    "window": 0,
    "irtt": 0,
    "iface": "ens33",
    "kind": "route",
    "route_flags_pretty": [
      "UP"
    ]
  }
]
```

```
$ jc route | jq
[
  {
    "destination": "default",
    "gateway": "gateway",
    "genmask": "0.0.0.0",
    "flags": "UG",
    "metric": 100,
    "ref": 0,
    "use": 0,
    "iface": "ens33",
    "flags_pretty": [
      "UP",
      "GATEWAY"
    ]
  },
  {
    "destination": "172.17.0.0",
    "gateway": "0.0.0.0",
    "genmask": "255.255.0.0",
    "flags": "U",
    "metric": 0,
    "ref": 0,
    "use": 0,
    "iface": "docker0",
    "flags_pretty": [
      "UP"
    ]
  },
  {
    "destination": "192.168.71.0",
    "gateway": "0.0.0.0",
    "genmask": "255.255.255.0",
    "flags": "U",
    "metric": 100,
    "ref": 0,
    "use": 0,
    "iface": "ens33",
    "flags_pretty": [
      "UP"
    ]
  }
]
```

Dozens of other commands are supported as well.

https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc

Comment: I advise readers against using this. `netstat` and `route` are **long time obsolete** in Linux — since ~1999, when new routing core was introduced together with `ip` utility from `iproute2`. It is certainly wrong to continue to use them in 2021, when even most conservative distributions (Debian) already don't have them installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the iproute2 utility supports --json option like

```
ip --json address show
ip --json link show

etc..
```

It lists all the configuration/statistics in JSON format.

But in some cases like route, it lists only the particular route table.
To list all the tables you can explicitly use the command:

```
ip --json route show table all
```

you can also get the particular table using their names like:

```
ip --json route show table default
```

[I dont know whether you already got the answer or not, If not I hope this would be helpful for you... Bye :) ]